# export the data from R to csv file

Tags: r

I have the code below from R. I want to export the data as csv file to I can use them with python. running the code below, it gives me the clustering results but it does not export the data. How can I solve this issue?

```
library(tidyverse)
library("fpc")
library(factoextra)
options(repr.plot.width=8, repr.plot.height=5)

set.seed(123)   #for reproducibility
sizes <- c(20, 100, 500)
centers <- data_frame(x = c(1, 4, 6), y = c(5, 0, 6), n = sizes,
                      cluster = factor(1:3))
df1 <- centers %>% group_by(cluster) %>%
    do(data_frame(x = rnorm(.$n, .$x), y = rnorm(.$n, .$y)))

km<- kmeans(df1, centers= 3)
df1$cluster = as.character(km$cluster)
df1 %>% ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, color  = cluster)) + geom_point() +
          ggtitle('R: Kmeans of unevenly sized clusters') +
          theme(axis.title = element_text(size=14), plot.title = 
            element_text(size = 16,colour="darkblue",hjust = 0.5))

write.csv(df1 %>% select(x,y), 'df1.csv', row.names = FALSE)  # to try out the same data with Python and Spark
```

Comment: Could you clarify what's the issue? If I run your code it creates a csv file containing you df1 data in my working directory.

Comment: Stefan, can you please share the csv file you got. I was not able to get it on my machine. it was giving me an error message of not able to understand  df1 %>%